# Custom resolution on Ubuntu server with XCFE and TightVNC

Tags: xfce, vnc, resolution

So I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide in order to be able to remotely connect to a new VPS (running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and have a GUI since I need to perform certain actions that require a visual interface.

Anyway, it worked fine and I can now run a VNC server and connect to it, however the resolution is very low (looks like 1024 x 768), and I cannot work out how to increase it.

There are no physical screens since it is a VPS, which means that xrandr doesn't work, can't even create virtual screens using it because whatever I try I seem to end up at `Can't open display`.

Does anyone know how I can increase the resolution (to something like 1920 x 1080)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the *resolution*, but you can set the desktop width and height on the `vncserver` command line. From `man vncserver`:

```
   -geometry widthxheight
          Set desktop width and height.
```

So for example

```
vncserver -geometry 1920x1080
```